# Mod_Rewrite - CSS and Images not found

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this is a very easy questions but I am really confused now. I tried several options but the result is the same: CSS file is not found if I use mod_rewrite

**What the solution should contain:**

1. domain.tld -> www.domain.tld
2. www.domain.tld/category/page-title -> index.php?a=category&b=page-title
3. www.domain.tld/category/page-title/ -> index.php?a=category&b=page-title
4. www.domain.tld/category -> index.php?a=category
5. www.domain.tld/category/ -> index.php?a=category

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.tld
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?a=$1 [L]
```

index.php:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/internal.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Does everything else work the way you are expecting it too? Specifically points 1 to 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your last rewrite rule is running without `RewriteCond` to skip real files/directories and is routing even js/css/image files to `index.php`.

Have it like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.tld
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]

# skip all files and directories from rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
```